# Gaussian Elimination with linear combination solution

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

In [Fundamental of Linear Algebra](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecarrell/NB.pdf) by James B. Carrell, there is a typical Gaussian reduction (his way of saying elimination) with homogeneous system of equation. The concept I understand, but one example to explain it got me confused.

> **Example 2.6.** Solve the following homogeneous linear system: $$\begin{equation}
> \left\{ \begin{aligned} 
>   0x + x_2 + 2x_3 + 0x_4 + 3x_5 - x_6 = 0\\
>   0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 +x_4 + 2x_5 + x_6 = 0
> \end{aligned} \right.
> \end{equation}$$

So yes, the augmented coefficient matrix is already in reduced row echelon form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But the author use a different coefficient matrix, which is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
without the last column of the other side of the equality. Next, he expresses the corner variable in terms of the free variables, i.e. the variables without coefficient $1$. Thus:
$$\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
x_2 = -2x_3 - 3x_5 + x_6\\
x_4 = -2x_5
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}$$

Let $\textbf{x}= (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)^{T}$ be the solution vector of the system with $\textbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^6$. Expressing the corners variables in terms of the free variables results in: $$\textbf{x}= (x_1,-2x_3 - 3x_5 + x_6,x_3,-2x_5,x_5,x_6)^{T}$$

which only depends on the free variable. Up to this point, everything seems alright. But the next thing is kind of confusing.

> The general solution vector now depends only on the free variables, and
> there is a solution for any choice of these variables.
> Using a little algebra, we can compute the vector coefficients of each one
> of the free variables in x. These vectors are called the fundamental solutions.
> In this example, the general solution vector $\textbf{x}$ has the form $$\textbf{x} = x_1 \mathbf{f_1} + x_3 \mathbf{f_2} + x_4 \mathbf{f_3} + x_5 \mathbf{f_4},$$

Now, at this point, I have some question:

- So, we are having a linear combination? Because I see vectors $\mathbf{f_1}$, $\mathbf{f_2}$, $\mathbf{f_3}$ and $\mathbf{f_4}$, with somewhat scalar (variable) multiplier. I thought Gaussian reduction gives us different form of solution?
- Of the above, we expressed corner variable in terms of the free variables, which is $x_2$ and $x_4$. However, the solution only has $x_1$, $x_3$, somehow $x_4$ and $x_5$. What happened to the others?
- What is the little *algebra* he is referring to? I do not understand how he did this part of the calculation.

Continuing, he present the exact coefficient vectors (somehow, it changed to vector coefficients), which is

$$
\mathbf{f}_1=\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right), \mathbf{f}_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right), \mathbf{f}_3=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{array}\right) \text {, and } \mathbf{f}_4=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array}\right) .
$$

I tried to decompose the solution, which is just adding them all up:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}
  xx_1 \\ -3x_4 - x_5 \\ -2x_3 \\ x_3 - 2x_4 \\ x_4 \\ x_5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which does not resemble that much the above steps given. I literally stuck here, and don't know how to explain, or try to reverse engineer it.

Any help is incredibly welcome, but I also want to have explanation and hints for me to follow through, trying to do it myself. Additionally, I want to know if the text is good enough, because personally, I may have to switch to another textbook.

Comment: You decided the best way to confront this problem, that is doing it yourself with a little hints. So let’s do it together. First just forget about this problem, it has hundreds of thousands variables :). Let’s just start with a system of 3 variables, try to describe the vectors $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $2x+z=0$. If you fully get this, you'll have no problem understanding the main problem.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb :D but why $(x,y,z)$ but only one equation, and without $y$? I will assume $y =0$ (since there are no bounds for $y$ in the question) here, and just solve the system by rearranging $2x+z=0$ for a second equation, then solve it?

Comment: You sound super brave bro! You chose to do it yourself that has 4 points if you’re familiar to Olympic wrestling. Back to the question. Let’s take a step back, tell me what are real numbers that satisfy the equation $0x=0$.

Comment: All numbers in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yup, Now look at the equation this way. $2x+0y+z=0$. Let's assume that we took care of $x$ and $z$, do you agree that there's no condition on $y$, so any $y$ should work here?

Comment: I think I am. There are also no conditions for it to be valid or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147772/discussion-between-ash-and-).